# Printing a string like "Hello {0}"

Tags: c#, .net

In an application I load strings from configuration of this format `stackoverflow.com?questionId={0}`. Obviously they're populated at run-time and used in query strings.

I want to log these strings at startup using a method:

```
void log(string message, params object[] vars)
        {
            string s = String.Format(message, vars);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

However as you would expect `String.Format` throws an exception because calling: `log(String.Format("Adding new feed '{0}'", "stackoverflow.com?questionId={0}"))` - `String.Format` tries to substitute `{0}` inside 'log()'.

Is there an easy way I can escape the `{` characters so substitution isn't attempted?

Comment: just double: `{0}`: `{{0}}`

Comment: But @DmitryBychenko then that breaks the actual _usage_... these are supposed to be substituted it's only the logging of them that is the problem.

Comment: ah, I see the dilemma. You can't have it both ways. You might need an overload to your log method that takes no `params` and doesn't call `string.format`. Voted to re-open since you're not asking "how to I quote placeholders", but "how do I sometimes pretend they're not placeholders"

Comment: Try: `log(@"stackoverflow.com?questionId={0}")` I'm not sure it will work but you can try.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I think the idea is to know when to do the escaping.

Comment: I think the nominated duplicate is the exact opposite of my question

Comment: Don't use `string.format()` then rather use string concatenation like `string str = "Adding new feed {0}" + string.format("stackoverflow.com?questionId={0}", value)`

Comment: Could you give us an example of calling your log function with parameters that cause the issue?

Comment: Could you leave the String.Format out of your call to log like this: log("Adding new feed '{0}'", "stackoverflow.com?questionId={0}");

Comment: You should always make it perfectly clear whether there's going to be a substitution or not. If you try to do anything smart, you're potentially opening yourself to security issues (and yes, lots of security issues are related to improper encoding/substitution). Only use `string.Format` if it is necessary, and always on data you have under control. Note how e.g. `Debug.WriteLine` has separate overloads for "just a string" and "a format string with values" - that's what you want.

Comment: @MartinBrown I think that would work, hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

I have found two answers to this.

Firstly, I escaped the braces by doing the following:

`log(String.Format("Adding new feed '{0}'", feedStr.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")));`

This works fine.

Secondly as suggested by **MartinBrown** I realised I could just do:

```
log("Adding new feed '{0}'", feedStr);
```